# Dynamically groupby on an array of objects by number of equal characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, group

What is the best way to groupby objects in an array ?

For example, given this array of objects:

```
[ 
    { MachineName: "10020784 machineTypeA P.", Value: "5" },
    { MachineName: "80346 machineTypeA s", Value: "10" },
    { MachineName: "80349 machineTypeA k", Value: "15" },
    { MachineName: "80427 machineTypeA w", Value: "20" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "25" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "30" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "35" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" }
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" }
    
]
```

What I’m looking for would be able to total specific values (if requested).

So if I did groupby MachineName, I’d want to receive:

```
  [
        { MachineName: " machineTypeA .", Value: "50" },
        { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "90" },
        { MachineName: "other", Value: "80" } 
  ]
```

I currently use the Array.prototype.some() function :

```
    Ausgabe = []    
    _.forEach(data, element => {  
          
          obj = {
         
            MachineName: element.MachineName,
            Value: element.Value,
          
          }
        Ausgabe.push(obj);
        
        })
        
         items1 = Ausgabe.filter(item => item.Anlage.indexOf('machineTypeA') !== -1);
         items2 = Ausgabe.filter(item => item.Anlage.indexOf('machineTypeX') !== -1);
         items3 = Ausgabe.filter(item => item.Anlage.indexOf('machineType') !== -1);

if (items1.length <= null){

} 
else {
for (var i = 0; i < items1.length; i++){ // DZ
  if (items1[i].Value <= null){
    //count ++;
     object1 = {
    MachineName : 'machineTypeA', 
  }   
}  else {
     if (items1[i].Value != null){
     object1 = {
    MachineName:'machineTypeA',
    Value: items1[i].Value , 
    
  }  
}
} 
}
 Ausgabe2.push(object1)
}

if (items2.length  <= null){

} else {
for (var i = 0; i < items2.length; i++){ // DZ
  if (items2[i].Value <= 0){
    //count ++;
     object2 = {
    MachineName : 'machineTypeX', 
  }   
}  else {
     if (items1[i].MRT != null){
     object2 = {
    Value : 'machineTypeX',
    MachineName : items2[i].Value , 
  }  
}
} 
}
 Ausgabe2.push(object2)
}


if(items3.length <= null){

} 
else {
for (var i = 0; i < items3.length; i++){ // DZ
  if (items3[i].Value <= 0){
    //count ++;
     object3 = {
    MachineName : 'machineTypeOther', 
  }   
}  else {
     if (items3[i].Value != null){
     object3 = {
    MachineName : 'machineTypeOther',
    Value : items3[i].Value , 
    
  }  
}
} 
}
 Ausgabe2.push(object3)
}
```

The problem I have with this solution is that its fine for a small array ,
but for a larger arrays its ineffective because I would need to create x number of 'items'.

If the MachineName would be equal I could use the following :

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

Is there a way to look for x amount of equal characters in a row and then group them accordingly ?

Comment: Couple of clarifications. **A)** `MachineName: " machineTypeA ."` ---> is the space before & after the `machineTypeA` and the last `.` required or just a typo. **B)** `{ MachineName: "other",` ---> does the name need to be `other` or is `machineTypeOther` acceptable?

Comment: Hi, A) the space before and after is required, I pull the data from an execl table and the names are given already. It is not a typo. machineTypeOther would be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

First we get all the unique names and filter out any that don't match your terms. Then using this unique list we filter the main array and sum the values using the reduce method.

```js
let arr = [ 
    { MachineName: "10020784 machineTypeA P.", Value: "5" },
    { MachineName: "80346 machineTypeA s", Value: "10" },
    { MachineName: "80349 machineTypeA k", Value: "15" },
    { MachineName: "80427 machineTypeA w", Value: "20" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "25" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "30" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "35" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
]
let terms = "machineType"
//Get unique list of Names and filter out ones not with your term;
let unique = [... new Set(arr.flatMap(m => m.MachineName.split(' ')).filter(n => n.includes(terms)))];
// Create a new array from those values and sum totals;
let resultObj = unique.map(m=> ({ 
  MachineName: m, 
  Value: arr
    .filter(i => i.MachineName.includes(m))
    .reduce((v,o) => v+=+o.Value,0) 
}))

console.log(resultObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to break the problem down.
First split all of the machine names from your list on empty space character, then get distinct values.
Next filter those values based on if the first character is a letter and the length is greater than *X*.

Finally use those filtered names to group the machine objects and Sum the values [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fmsy3l).

```
    int minimumLengthOfName = 3;
    var machines = new[] 
    {
        new { MachineName= "10020784 machineTypeA P.", Value= "5" },
        new { MachineName= "80346 machineTypeA s", Value= "10" },
        new { MachineName= "80349 machineTypeA k", Value= "15" },
        new { MachineName= "80427 machineTypeA w", Value= "20" },
        new { MachineName= "machineTypeX", Value= "25" },
        new { MachineName= "machineTypeX", Value= "30" },
        new { MachineName= "machineTypeX", Value= "35" },
        new { MachineName= "machineTypeOther", Value= "40" },
        new { MachineName= "machineTypeOther", Value= "40" }
    };

    var names = machines.Select(x=> x.MachineName);
    var filteredNames = names.SelectMany(x=> x.Split(' ')) // Split MachineName on empty space and get as a list
        .Distinct() // Get distinct values from out list of split strings
        .Where(x=> Char.IsLetter(x[0]) && x.Length >= minimumLengthOfName); // Get where first character is a letter and the length is greater or equal to minimumLengthOfName
    
    // Now we have each unique machine name we can loop through them and total the matching machines values
    foreach(var name in filteredNames){
        var total = machines.Where(x=> x.MachineName.Contains(name))
            .Sum(x=> Int32.Parse(x.Value));
        Console.WriteLine("MachineName: {0}, Value {1}", name, total);
    }
```

Comment: Hey Sean, you might want to check the language, this is a Javascript question.

Comment: @Pellay oops! lol

Comment: No worries, it happens. You never know, someone might find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean order by? Otherwise use [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

```js
const collection = [{
    MachineName: "10020784 machineTypeA P.",
    Value: "5"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "80346 machineTypeA s",
    Value: "10"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "80349 machineTypeA k",
    Value: "15"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "80427 machineTypeA w",
    Value: "20"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "machineTypeX",
    Value: "25"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "machineTypeX",
    Value: "30"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "machineTypeX",
    Value: "35"
  },
  {
    MachineName: "machineTypeOther",
    Value: "40"
  }, {
    MachineName: "machineTypeOther",
    Value: "40"
  }
];

const ordered = _.orderBy(collection, 'MachineName');
console.log(ordered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarifications provided by OP on the comments below the question, the below solution is being provided.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const groupAndSum = arr => (
  Object.values(          // return only the "values" from the result-obect
    arr.map(              // simplify the "MachineName" to machineTypeA, X, O
      ({ MachineName: mn, Value}) => ({
        MachineName: `machineType${mn.split('machineType')[1][0]}`,
        Value
    })).map(              // transform "MachineName" to desired objective
      ({ MachineName: mn, Value}) => ({
        MachineName: 
          mn.at(-1) === 'A'       // if "A", prefix, suffix space and suffix "."
          ? ` ${mn} .`
          : mn.at(-1) === 'O'     // if "O", transform to "Other"
            ? `${mn}ther` : mn,   // if "X" (or anything else) "machineTypeX"
        Value
    })).reduce(                   // now, group by machine and sum values
      (acc, { MachineName: mn, Value}) => {
          acc[mn] = {
            MachineName: mn,
            Value: (acc?.[mn]?.Value ?? 0) + +Value
          };
          return acc;
      },
      {}                          // result of "reduce" is an object (initially empty)
    )
  )                 // the "Object.values()" extracts the values of the above object
);

let origArr = [ 
    { MachineName: "10020784 machineTypeA P.", Value: "5" },
    { MachineName: "80346 machineTypeA s", Value: "10" },
    { MachineName: "80349 machineTypeA k", Value: "15" },
    { MachineName: "80427 machineTypeA w", Value: "20" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "25" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "30" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeX", Value: "35" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
    { MachineName: "machineTypeOther", Value: "40" },
];

console.log(groupAndSum(origArr));
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the above snippet provide description of the significant steps.